# Clear description of PCA using SVD of covariance matrix

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, svd

After reading thousands of articles on PCA and SVD, using them in a number of programming frameworks and even implementing similar techniques (like Random Indexing) I found out that I still have doubts about some parts of PCA for dimension reduction. So let me show what I know and what I have doubts about.

Let's say we have $N$ observations of $M$-dimensional data, organized as matrix $A \in R^{N * M}$. To perform PCA we should first compute MLE estimate of covariance matrix $\Sigma \in R^{M*M}$:

$$\Sigma=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N(x_i - \bar x)(x_i - \bar x)^T$$

where $x_i \in R^M$ is $i$-th observation, $\bar x = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}x_k \in R^M$ is mean observation.

Then we can decompose $\Sigma$ using SVD as follows:

$$\Sigma = USV^T$$

Now here are several things I'm not sure about:

1. What are **dimensions** of $U$, $S$ and $V^T$?
2. In $USV^T$ what exactly is considered as **eigenvalues** and which of them should I use as **principal components**?
3. How can I **project** original observations $x_i$ onto new reduced space and vice versa?

**UPD.** There's a different way to compute PCA using SVD - by factorizing data matrix ($A$ here) instead of covariance matrix ($\Sigma = AA^T$). Good description for this process may be found in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3869/what-is-the-intuitive-relationship-between-svd-and-pca) answer.

Comment: Please excuse if it sounds rude, but... where are you stuck `after reading thousands of articles on PCA`?

Comment: @ttnphns: the problem is that different articles use different terms and make emphasis on different parts. For example, in some articles they use terms "left eigenvalues" to refer to columns of $U$ and "right eigenvalues" to refer to rows of $V^T$, but they don't say which of them should I use for PCA. Also different notations are used for projection of original vector onto reduced space - normally it is written as $x' = Px$ (where $P$ is matrix of first $k$ eigenvectors), but I have also seen following form, that breaks down my understanding of used dimensions: $x' = \sum p_i x$

Comment: So this question is caused not by little number of articles read, but by mixing ideas and notations in that articles. What I actually want is to bring some order in my thoughts. I have my own opinion on all 3 questions, but it's always worth to make sure when dealing with rigorous maths.

Comment: I hoped you know that because covariance matrix is symmetric U=V (with columns corresponding to the PCs) and is the same eigenvectors matrix as eigen-decomposition returns, and S's diagonal are the same PCs eigenvalues as eigen-decomposition returns.

Comment: Ah, symmetry of $U$ and $V$ is just what I missed. This explains many things in articles that confused me and proves assumptions I had about my 3 questions. Thanks, you saved me from doubts :)

Comment: @ttnphns If you have time and inclination, could you please convert your comment as an answer so that the OP could accept it and close this thread?

Comment: I know this is a very old question, but I find it very unfortunately formulated. When people talk about using SVD for PCA, they mean SVD of the data matrix itself (matrix $A$ in your question), as opposed to doing eigendecomposition of the covariance matrix. But you are asking about SVD of the covariance matrix, which is square symmetric matrix, and so its SVD is equivalent to its eigendecomposition! So the question itself is asking something very different (and much more trivial) than what the title implies.

Comment: [cont.] It would be most useful for this site and for the community to rewrite the question such that it asks about SVD of the matrix $A$, but this requires significant changes. If you don't want to do that, I can understand, but then perhaps we should edit the title to clarify what it's about.

Comment: @amoeba: changing question is not an option here, because in this case the answer below will lose any sense. So I simply linked a different question (see update) and change the title. Please, feel free to refine the post further if you see better formulation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- What are **dimensions** of $U$, $S$ and $V^T$?

Since $\Sigma$ is a M by M matrix, the three matrices $U$, $S$, $V^T$ wil be all M by M matrices. Because applying SVD on a N by M matrix, you will get $U_{N{\times}N}$, $S_{N{\times}M}$, and $V^T_{M{\times}M}$. You can verify that in matlab. When you truncate the singular values $S$ you also should remove the corresponding parts in $U$ and $V^T$.

- In $USV^T$ what exactly is considered as **eigenvalues** and which of them should I use as **principal components**?

PCA should be done by doing eigenvalue decomposition on the covariance matrix $\Sigma$, or done by applying SVD on $A$. The left singular vectors of $SVD(A)$ come from the eigen vectors of $AA^T$, and the right singular vectors of $SVD(A)$ are from the eigenvectors of $A^TA$. But you need to order them according to the eigenvalues from large to small, and make them orthonormal. $A^TA$ is called Gram Matrix and is related to the covariance matrix $\Sigma$. If the dimensional vectors in $A$ (M of them totally) are all centered already, Gram Matrix = N * Covariance matrix. Check Wikipedia and some tutorials of SVD and PCA.

- How can I **project** original observations $x_i$ onto new reduced space and vice versa?

If applying SVD on $A$ for PCA, it would be $u_i*S$; if applying eigen decomposition on covariance matrix $\Sigma$, and $V$ is eigenvectors of $\Sigma$, it is $x_i*V$.

Comment: just want to add that PCA = eigen decomposition on the covariance matrix  = centering the data matrix A + SVD on the centered A. In this way you will find the singular value of the centered A and the eigenvalue of \sigma are the same.